# Github Actions does not export citations from Emacs org-mode

Tags: html, emacs, github-actions, github-pages, org-mode

I want to use github actions to export org-mode files via ox-publish to html and publish the result as a gh-page. With some inspiration from [systemcrafters](https://systemcrafters.net/publishing-websites-with-org-mode/automated-site-publishing/) this works rather well.

However, citations are not properly exported from org-mode. The weird part is that everything works nicely if I run the build script locally on my machine (it produces a index.html in the folder "public" that has properly formatted references) but fails to work when it is run by github actions.

My test repository is https://github.com/schottmueller/test and the unsuccessful result is https://schottmueller.github.io/test/

Comment: I may be barking up the wrong tree here, but if you are using the citation support in `oc.el`, that wasn't added until Org 9.5. If you are using `org-ref` that is an external package. In either case, the Org mode that is used on Github to publish in gh-pages is too old for the first (your failed test says that Org mode 9.3 is used); or there might be no provision to load external packages at all. Is there a build log that you can examine for failures?

Comment: Very good call. Indeed gh uses org-mode 9.3 and I try to use oc.el. So I either have to switch to org-ref or get gh-pages to update to a more current version of org-mode.

Comment: The solution was to change the way I install Emacs in the .yml file. Installing Emacs through snap (sudo snap install emacs --classic) gives the newest version of Emacs with a a relatively new version of org-mode as well.